# Yu-Gi-Oh Magic/Trap cards that are based on how many tributes I had that turn

Tags: yu-gi-oh

I have a [Majespecter](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Majespecter) [Amorphage](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Amorphage) deck where I basically tribute a monster every turn.

Are there any magic or trap cards that give me effects based on how many tributes I had that turn or if I tributed at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> are there any magic or trap cards that give me effects based on how many tributes I had that turn or if I tributed at all?

Perhaps the most effective and generic card that comes to mind is [Trial and Tribulation](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Trial_and_Tribulation):

> You can only activate 1 "Trial and Tribulation" per turn. during the End Phase of the turn this card was activated, apply this effect, depending on the number of monsters you Tributed from the field and from your hand this turn, except Tokens.
>
> - 1: Draw 1 card.
> - 2: Add 2 monsters from your Graveyard to your hand.
> - 3+: Destroy up to 3 face-up card on the field.

As you can see it is quite powerful and will benefit from tributing monsters (even from your hand).

Comment: Ahh! I have that card and didn't know it! Are there any others? preferably continuous. I appreciate it a lot I've spent a lot of time looking for these cards.

Comment: @Odell Lair of Darkness comes to mind, it is a field spell so it counts as continuous